# Left click not working Arch Linux KDE

Tags: terminal, mouse, arch-linux, kde

I run Arch-Linux on a Intel i3 processor w/ x64 architecture.
I installed arch Linux and other than gdm failing and preventing me from booting, it went pretty smoothly. For the longest time, I used two Desktop environments: root ran KDE, and I used Xfce4. I had it configured to start x on log in for both of us. I recently had decided to switch to KDE, but when I did, my left click stopped working. Not immediately either. I was able to add Konsole and one application to my favorites before my device developed Lou Gherig's. I can move the cursor around with both devices, but my left click, and my right click have been disabled on both touchscreen and mouse. I would revert to the last functioning state, but to open konsole, I need to click the Icon. I can't summon it with `meta+F2` because I need to click in the text bar; and `C-M-t` brought it up, but I couldn't focus into it, nor drop in a cursor to do the command line revision. I can't ssh into it because WiFi is disabled by default. The next viable option is to boot into a live OS, chroot into it and run the commands, but it is an arduous, repetitive, and time consuming task; even if it works on the first attempt. I can't go by Ethernet, because there is no Ethernet in my house, and to get the IP address, I need to, in console, I have to type ip addr show; but I can't do that for the previously mentioned reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. Turned out, KDE Plasma had just such a high overhead, it took 3 whole hours for a mouse click to recognize. Now that I have switched back to XFCE, my only problem is now tring to connect to the internet.

EDIT:
You can also do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> to drop down to are bare text terminal, `killall kde` && `ip a`, or just directrly to `ip a` and take care of things that way.